# Disabling an element inside of another element EXCEPT when it's a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button that disables and enables elements inside of a div.

The button lives inside of the div.

When I click the button, it disables all elements inside of the div, including the button. I do not want the button disabled.

What I've already tried is below:

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#overrideButton').click(function() {
        $('#returnSkuInfo *').each(function() {
            var isDisabled = $(this).prop('disabled');
                if (isDisabled) {
                    if ($(this).not('#overridebutton')) {
                        $(this).prop('disabled', false);
                    }
                }
                else if (!isDisabled) {
                    if ($(this).not('#overridebutton')) {
                        $(this).prop('disabled', true);
                    }
                }
        });
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="returnSkuInfo">
    <button id="overrideButton">Override</button>
    <input disabled/>
    <input disabled/>
    <select disabled>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
    </select>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Infomation</td>
            <td>More Info</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

This is not working, however, because when the button is clicked, the button gets disabled. I need this code to ignore the button.

How do I get this to ignore the button and not disable the button?

Comment: Can you post the HTML too?

Comment: HTML posted @j08691.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go `:)`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#overrideButton').click(function() {
        var t = $(this);
        $('#returnSkuInfo').children().not(t).each(function() {
            var isDisabled = $(this).prop('disabled');
            if (isDisabled) {
                $(this).prop('disabled', false);
            }else if (!isDisabled) {
                $(this).prop('disabled', true);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Lt2v0mxv/1/

---

Want to make it more specific:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#overrideButton').click(function() {
        var t = $(this);
        $('#returnSkuInfo').find('button, select, textarea, input').not(t).each(function() {
            var isDisabled = $(this).prop('disabled');
            if (isDisabled) {
                $(this).prop('disabled', false);
            }else if (!isDisabled) {
                $(this).prop('disabled', true);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lt2v0mxv/2/

---

If you want to ignore specific elements use `class="ignore"` on the elements and use the following jQuery (with HTML example):

**HTML**

```
<div id="returnSkuInfo">
    <button id="overrideButton" class="ignore">Override</button>
    <input disabled >
    <input disabled >
    <select disabled >
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
    </select>
        <input class="ignore" disabled>
        <textarea disabled></textarea>
        <button disabled>More Info...</button>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Infomation</td>
            <td>More Info</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#overrideButton').click(function() {
    var i = $('.ignore');
    $('#returnSkuInfo').find('button, select, textarea, input').not(i).each(function() {
        var isDisabled = $(this).prop('disabled');
        if (isDisabled) {
            $(this).prop('disabled', false);
        }else if (!isDisabled) {
            $(this).prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lt2v0mxv/3/

Comment: Ah this is awesome! Thanks! What if I wanted to ignore more elements in the future? I may be adding a textarea box and would not want the button to change the disabled status of that. How would I add another element to ignore?

Comment: You can change your selector from `.children()` to `.find()` and inside the find put the classes/id's/tags of the elements you want to change. This way if you put another button in you keep the `.not(t)`.

Comment: @aCarella for example see my addition above

Comment: This is great. How would I go about using your exact code (`.find('button, select, textarea, input').not(t)`), but ignoring one of the input elements?

Comment: I just learned a ton of jQuery from your help. Thanks a lot. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to be more specific in your selector and select only the elements you want to affect, rather than all of them; so I'd suggest:

```
$('#overrideButton').click(function() {
    // getting only the <input /> and <select> descendants:
    $('#returnSkuInfo').find('input, select')
        // updating the disabled property, using the
        // anonymous function:
        .prop('disabled', function(i,v){
          // v (the second argument) contains the current value
          // of the property, here we simply return its inverse:
          return !v;
        });
});
```

```js
$('#overrideButton').click(function() {
  $('#returnSkuInfo').find('input, select').prop('disabled', function(i, v) {
    return !v;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="returnSkuInfo">
  <button id="overrideButton">Override</button>
  <input disabled/>
  <input disabled/>
  <select disabled>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Infomation</td>
      <td>More Info</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

You could, of course, select all the elements and then filter out specific elements by their `id`, or via other identifiers, such as `class`-names or `data-*` attributes, using the `not()` method:

```
$('#overrideButton').click(function() {
  // selecting all the child elements:
  $('#returnSkuInfo').children()
      // removing unwanted elements (using an id in this case):
      .not('#overrideButton')
      // as above:
      .prop('disabled', function(i, v) {
          return !v;
      });
});
```

```js
$('#overrideButton').click(function() {
  $('#returnSkuInfo').children().not('#overrideButton').prop('disabled', function(i, v) {
    return !v;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="returnSkuInfo">
  <button id="overrideButton">Override</button>
  <input disabled/>
  <input disabled/>
  <select disabled>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Infomation</td>
      <td>More Info</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

References:

- [`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/).
- [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Answer (score 1):

Many ways to skin a cat here. I tried to simplify your branching a little bit, and I cached vars that we'd be reusing so it wouldn't be too memory-intensive.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //this is our main entrypoint into the dom
  var $returnSkuInfo = $('#returnSkuInfo');
 //click event on parent element 
  $returnSkuInfo.click(function(e) {
  /* this is the jquery object generated by $('#returnSkuInfo') */
  var $parent = $(this),
      /* find the button obj from the parent el (better performance) */
      $button = $parent.find('#overideButton'),
      /*actual markup of the button we'll use to compare below*/
      button = $button[0],
     /*the actual elements we want to toggle disable for, without the button*/
        $toDisable =  $button.siblings();

   if ($(e.target).context === button && $toDisable.attr('disabled') ) {    
     $toDisable.removeAttr('disabled');
   } else if ($(e.target).context === button) {
      $toDisable.attr('disabled', 'true');
   }
});
```

});